# Upload photos from camera into social networks instantly?

Tags: tethering, wireless, file-transfer, facebook

I organize table tennis tournaments. During the day we take pictures of the matches and then upload them into Facebook albums.

What do you recommend me to upload photos right after each of them were taken?

I head there are Eye-Fi cards so called, do they work if the camera doesn't have Wi-Fi? do they work fine?

I was thinking there may exist some software that connects to the camera via USB and enables you to put photos on Facebook just by checking on them.

Comment: What camera do you have currently, and do you value image quality over speed to upload, or the other way around?

Comment: I sell software that automatically upload photos - but the current version only works with SmugMug not with Facebook (it's at http://GiraffeUpload.com ) - if this is what you are looking for (just with Facebook support) send me a message using the software's site contact form

Answer (score 5):

There are five possible methods that I can think of:

**Tethering to a Computer**

You can connect the camera to a computer via USB. However, this limits movement and can be inconvenient at times. This also requires specialized software. This is the cheapest option by far. You will still need a conection to the internet.

**An Eye-Fi card**

The second cheapest method would be to get an Eye-Fi card.They do not require the camera to have Wi-Fi and are able to link directly to social media. This, unlike tethering, allows you to move around without restriction. However, there must be a WiFi network present.

**A compact camera with WiFI**

Some compact cameras have a built-in upload to the web feature that doesn't require any further equipment. Many of Samsung's cameras have this feature. Nikon and Canon also have cameras with built-in WiFi. This would give you slightly more control than the Eye-Fi cards. This gives you the same range of movement as the Eye-Fi, and also requires a WiFi network.

**A smart camera**

Finally, both Nikon and Samsung even have cameras that run Android. They can then run photo apps, giving you further options for upload. This is more expensive than the previous options, but gives you the most control. Another benefit is that both of these can connect to cellular towers, giving you connectivity in places without WiFi.

**A DSLR with WiFi**

For the most photographic control and best photos, I would reccommend getting a DSLR. Some come with built-in WiFi. If you have one already, there are accessories that will work with the camera. Most can also accept an Eye-Fi card.

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Four main options exist:

- Cameras with built in Wi-Fi
- Use an Eye-Fi card
- Tether the camera to a computer that can upload the images
- Shoot with a camera that also has the ability to upload to Facebook, such as a smartphone camera

**Eye-Fi** can in fact do this. They have a webpage dedicated to the functionality you are interested in here: http://www.eye.fi/features/online-sharing

Eye-Fi cards add Wi-Fi functionality to your camera(more specifically to your memory card), so of course your camera doesn't need Wi-Fi for it to work. Make sure that your camera is compatible with a Wi-Fi card before just purchasing one though.

As you guessed, yes you can also connect some cameras to the computer in what is called **tethering** to download photos to the computer.

A third option would be to buy a camera that has built in Wi-Fi capabilities. This [search](http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras#criterias=SpecsCoreParams,SpecsWireless&includeDiscontinued=No&sort=newestFirst&view=list&page=1&paramSpecsCoreParamsBodyType=&paramSpecsWireless=BuiltIn) will show you currently available cameras with Wi-Fi capabilities.

**What would I recommend?** Eye-Fi can be kind of picky, but if you happen to already own a  fully compatible camera(which you very well might) I think this might be the easiest and cheapest route. If quality isn't paramount but speed to upload is, then a smartphone is really quick and easy to get a fast data connection anywhere with. Finally, if quality is the top priority, look for a DSLR with Wi-Fi accessories or built in, or tether if you don't mind the cord attached while shooting. So I didn't really answer directly - because **they all have their place depending on your needs**.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what camera you are looking for - if you are using/looking for a DSLR, yes, **Eye-Fi cards** are what come to the mind first. While these are more expensive than regular SD/SDHC cards, they offer the cheapest *upgrade*, if I may call it - to a wi-fi ready setting. But I am not sure if you can actually directly upload the images to the web using this option.

There are, of course, some **DSLRs with wi-fi** - these are probably the most expensive option. While I have never seen one up close, BestBuy has some of them listed out [here](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/olstemplatemapper.jsp?id=pcat17080&type=page&qp=cabcat0400000%23%230%23%23dh~~cabcat0401000%23%230%23%233e~~cabcat0401005%23%230%23%23k~~nf1166%7C%7C57692d4669205265616479&list=y&nrp=15&sc=abCameraCamcorderSP&ks=960&usc=abcat0400000&sp=-bestsellingsort+skuid&list=y&iht=n&st=processingtime%3A%3E1900-01-01&gf=y). Most of these are pro-sumer cameras, but I thought they are worth a look in case if you are shopping for a new DSLR.

(*Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with BestBuy in any way; that was the first link - and only one in the first page - in [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=dslr+wifi) that provides a nice list of Wi-fi DSLRs.*)

And, if you are instead looking for a digital camera, there are some pretty good cameras with **built-in wi-fi** out there at decent prices. [This Gizmodo article](http://gizmodo.com/5903007/the-best-inexpensive-point+and+shoot-camera-with-wi+fi) reviews two such ones, the [Canon Elph 320 HS](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/digital_cameras/powershot_elph_320_hs_blue) and [Samsung WB150f](http://www.samsung.com/us/photography/digital-cameras/EC-WB150FBPBUS).

The Canon seems to be the sleeker of the two minimal buttons and a touch-screen, while the Samsung offers "more control over the image-taking".

> Both the Canon and Samsung cameras use their Wi-Fi powers in two ways. They can upload images to an online storage service using an existing wi-fi network in the area, or they can use the cameras' built-in wi-fi transmitters to establish a direct wireless connection with a smartphone, tablet, or computer.

I would advice you to choose what fits your needs and budget the most.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which camera you have, so we don't know your particular options. Here I will assume you have some kind of DSLR, either Nikon or Canon:

*Only if your camera uses SD cards* can you use the Eye-Fi cards, which would be the easiest way.

You can also buy a battery grip with wifi built-in, if it is available for your camera model, but these are really expensive.

If none of these are possible you need to use the usb cable. I never liked that so I take out the card into a card reader as it is much faster, open the folder, select the ones I want and batch resize, so there's less Mb to upload.